# Reopen "Specialist Roles Killing my ability to leave" (REOPENED)

Tags: discussion

Could we reopen: 
[Specialist roles killing my ability to leave](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92003/specialist-roles-killing-my-ability-to-leave)

I edited the final line to bring it in-line with being on topic and removed the "has anyone experienced this.

The question is essentially how to avoid being pigeon holed in a narrow discipline.

While this question is about IT, I think it does bring up a very real workplace situation on how many people end up getting dead ended in their careers due to an overly specialized and narrow skillset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just cast reopen vote    #5.